# Copypasting then deleting rows in a For Each loop skips every other row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm searching through a range for any cell that has a strikethrough, if a strikethrough is detected, then that entire row will get copypasted to another worksheet of the same workbook.

I'm also searching all cells above the cell that had the strikethrough, looking for the first cell with an interior.color = rgb(0,0,0) and once found it will place that data on the other worksheet as well.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ipWS As Worksheet, compWS As Worksheet
Dim compDest As Range, rrCell As Range
Dim alastRow As Long

Set ipWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("In Processing")
Set compWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")
Set compDest = compWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

alastRow = ipWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rackRng As Range
Dim cellRng As Range
 
Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

For Each rrCell In ipWS.Range("A1:A" & alastRow).Cells

    If rrCell.Font.Strikethrough = True Then
    
        Set cellRng = ipWS.Range(rrCell, rrCell.End(xlToRight))
        cellRng.Copy compDest.Offset(0, 1)
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
        Set rackRng = ipWS.Range(rrCell, rrCell.End(xlUp)).Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious, , , SearchFormat:=True)
        rackRng.Copy compDest
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
        ipWS.Range(rrCell, rrCell.End(xlToRight)).EntireRow.Delete
            
        Set compDest = compDest.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next rrCell
   
With compWS.Range("A:P")
    .Font.Strikethrough = False
    .ColumnWidth = 25
    .Font.Size = 14
    .WrapText = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
End With

End Sub
```

The code works if I have < 2 cells with a strikethrough.  Once I have > 2 cells with a strikethrough it starts recognizing every other cell with a strikethrough and leaves those on the original worksheet.

If I hit the button again, then the ones that were skipped then move to the destination worksheet.

Here's some pics
[image]

[image: skipped cells]

[image: destination worksheet]

The second picture is the result of the first time I click the button. It recognizes the first cell with strikethrough, then skips the next one, then grabs the third one.
If I press the button again, then the one that was skipped will then go to the worksheet.

`Application.cutcopymode = false` is commented out because that didn't seem to work.

I tried calling out both worksheets at every opportunity but that didn't work.

Comment: Since you are deleting the rows in a loop, you need to use a reverse loop `For i = alastRow to 1 Step -1` instead of `For Each rrCell In ipWS.Range("A1:A" & alastRow).Cells`

Comment: Ahh, I believe I did come across this option in my search, but tried making it work with what I already had, haha.  I appreciate the help!  Another opportunity to learn something new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip in the right direction @Siddharth Rout.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ipWS As Worksheet, compWS As Worksheet
Dim compDest As Range, rrCell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim alastRow As Long

Set ipWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("In Processing")
Set compWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")


alastRow = ipWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Dim rackRng As Range
Dim cellRng As Range

Set compDest = compWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)


For i = alastRow To 1 Step -1

            
            If Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Font.Strikethrough = True Then
           
                Set rackRng = ipWS.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1).End(xlUp)).Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious, , , SearchFormat:=True)
                    rackRng.Copy compDest
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy compDest.Offset(0, 1)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                        Set compDest = compDest.Offset(1, 0)
                    
                    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

Next i
            With compWS.Range("A:P")
                .Font.Strikethrough = False
                .ColumnWidth = 25
                .Font.Size = 14
                .WrapText = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With

End Sub
```